# Side effects in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, side-effects, purely-functional

I am learning Scala right in these days. I have a slight familiarity with Haskell, although I cannot claim to know it well.

**Parenthetical remark for those who are not familiar with Haskell**

One trait that I like in Haskell is that not only functions are first-class citizens, but side effects (let me call them actions) are. An action that, when executed, will endow you with a value of type `a`, belongs to a specific type `IO a`. You can pass these actions around pretty much like any other value, and combine them in interesting ways.

In fact, *combining* the side effects is the only way in Haskell to do something with them, as you cannot execute them. Rather, the program that *will* be executed, is the combined action which is returned by your `main` function. This is a neat trick that allows functions to be pure, while letting your program actually do something other than consuming power.

The main advantage of this approach is that the compiler is aware of the parts of the code where you perform side effects, so it can help you catch errors with them.

**Actual question**

Is there some way in Scala to have the compiler type check side effects for you, so that - for instance - you are guaranteed not to execute side effects inside a certain function?

Comment: I'd been making parenthetical remarks, both in public written form and in my own thoughts, for some time. But I didn't know their name. By accident you have educated me.

#upvoting

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, this is not possible in principle in Scala, as the language does not enforce referential transparency -- the language semantics are oblivious to side effects. Your compiler will not track and enforce freedom from side effects for you.

You will be able to use the type system to [tag some actions](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/towards-an-effect-system-in-scala-part-2-io-monad/) as being of `IO` type however, and with programmer discipline, get some of the compiler support, but without the compiler proof.

Comment: Thank you, the post you link looks very interesting! It is exactly something along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

The ability to enforce referential transparency this is pretty much incompatible with Scala's goal of having a class/object system that is interoperable with Java.

Java code can be impure in arbitrary ways (and may not be available for analysis when the Scala compiler runs) so the Scala compiler would have to assume *all* foreign code is impure (assigning them an `IO` type). To implement pure Scala code with calls to Java, you would have to wrap the calls in something equivalent to `unsafePerformIO`. This adds boilerplate and makes the interoperability much less pleasant, but it gets worse.

Having to assume that all Java code is in `IO` unless the programmer promises otherwise would pretty much kill inheriting from Java classes. All the inherited methods would have to be assumed to be in the `IO` type; this would even be true of interfaces, since the Scala compiler would have to assume the existence of an impure implementation somewhere out there in Java-land. So you could never derive a Scala class with any non-`IO` methods from a Java class or interface.

Even worse, even for classes defined in Scala, there could theoretically be an untracked subclass defined in Java with impure methods, whose instances might be passed back in to Scala as instances of the parent class. So unless the Scala compiler can *prove* that a given object could not possibly be an instance of a class defined by Java code, it must assume that any method call on that object might call code that was compiled by the Java compiler without respecting the laws of what functions returning results not in `IO` can do. This would force almost *everything* to be in `IO`. But putting everything in `IO` is exactly equivalent to putting nothing in `IO` and just not tracking side effects!

So ultimately, Scala *encourages* you to write pure code, but it makes no attempt to enforce that you do so. As far as the compiler is concerned, any call to anything can have side effects.

Comment: This is a great answer, but accepted Don's one for the intriguing link