# Why doesn't Scala optimize calls to the same Extractor?

Tags: scala, matching, extractor

Take the following example, why is the extractor called multiple times as opposed to temporarily storing the results of the first call and matching against that. Wouldn't it be reasonable to assume that results from `unapply` would not change given the same string.

```
object Name {
  val NameReg = """^(\w+)\s(?:(\w+)\s)?(\w+)$""".r

  def unapply(fullName: String): Option[(String, String, String)] = {
    val NameReg(fname, mname, lname) = fullName
    Some((fname, if (mname == null) "" else mname, lname))
  }
}

"John Smith Doe" match {
  case Name("Jane", _, _) => println("I know you, Jane.")
  case Name(f, "", _) => println(s"Hi ${f}")
  case Name(f, m, _) => println(s"Howdy, ${f} ${m}.")
  case _ => println("Don't know you")
}
```

Comment: In general, it's impossible to decide if a a function is pure. See, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620395/side-effects-in-scala. Given (I think) is is documented that cases are checked in order, it would be possible (but very poor style) to write an unapply that relied on side-effects.

Comment: @Paul: But the specification for how extractors are used in match-statements _could_ have been designed so that it allowed for this kind of optimisations, even if they would be observable on extractors with side effects. So this question still remains.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't  There are two different questions here - the one asked is, I believe, why doesn't the compiler optimise this today, the answer is because it can't prove the unapply is pure and the spec doesn't ban unapply with side-effects. If the question is "could the language spec be changed to allow this optimisation", then the answer is clearly yes. But that's not the question asked

Comment: Come on! An answer to a question about the design of a programming language that starts and ends with "spec sais so" is a very poor answer. Why is the spec this way? I want to know too!

Comment: A lot of things in Scala are like this, because Scala was initially designed as an improved Java with a focus on Java compatibility. So early features, in particular, are specified so as to "play nice" with idiomatic Java, i.e. code with side effects. @som-snytt's answer tells us that a newer feature was specified differently, so that the spec remains this way is probably more due to compatibility than due to this being the best tradeoff for today's Scala community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be reasonable to assume that results from `unapply` would not change given the same string.

Unfortunately, *assuming* isn't good enough for a (static) compiler. In order for memoizing to be a legal optimization, the compiler has to *prove* that the expression being memoized is pure and referentially transparent. However, in the general case, this is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

It would certainly be possible to write an optimization pass which *tries* to prove purity of certain expressions and memoizes them iff and only iff it succeeds, but that may be more trouble than it's worth. Such proofs get very hard very quickly, so they are only likely to succeed for very trivial expressions, which execute very quickly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What is a pattern match? The spec says it matches the "shape" of the value and binds vars to its "components."

In the realm of mutation, you have questions like, if I match on `case class C(var v: V)`, does a `case C(x)` capture the mutable field? Well, the answer was no:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5158

The spec says (sorry) that order of evaluation may be changed, so it recommends against side-effects:

> In the interest of efficiency the evaluation of a pattern matching
>   expression may try patterns in some other order than textual sequence.
>   This might affect evaluation through side effects in guards.

That's in relation to guard expressions, presumably because extractors were added after case classes.

There's no special promise to evaluate extractors exactly once. (Explicitly in the spec, that is.)

The semantics are only that "patterns are tried in sequence".

Also, your example for regexes can be simplified, since a regex will not be re-evaluated when unapplied to its own Match. See the [example in the doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.matching.Regex). That is,

```
Name.NameReg findFirstMatchIn s map {
  case Name("Jane",_,_) =>
}
```

where

```
object Name { def unapply(m: Regex.Matcher) = ... }
```